# Getting orientdb-gremlin-parent error compiling OrientDB Develop branch with Tinkerpop Gremlin 3.0

Tags: orientdb, tinkerpop3

I'm loving OrientDB 2.2.x. Eazy to install and configure, including Gremlin graph (2.6.0). But our team needs TinkerPop Gremlin 3.0. I see that this will be available in the OrientDB 3.0 version due in the next few months. I'd like to try it out now using the develop branch of orientdb-gremlin. 
https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb-gremlin/tree/develop

The documentation for installing and configuring the GA version of OrientDB is super. However I'm having a difficult time figuring out for the develop branch of orientdb-gremlin. I see instructions for OrientDB (not orientdb-gremlin) Source Code Installation here:
http://orientdb.com/docs/2.2/Tutorial-Installation.html

This is helpful. But I'm getting this error when I try to compile orientdb-gremlin:

[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM for com.orientechnologies:orientdb-gremlin-parent:[unknown-version]: Could not find artifact com.orientechnologies:orientdb-parent:pom:3.0.0-SNAPSHOT and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM @ line 15, column 13 -> [Help 2]

The relevant section of the pom.xml file is:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.orientechnologies</groupId>
    <artifactId>orientdb-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath/>
</parent>
```

The commands I ran to get to this point:

```
git clone https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb-gremlin.git

cd orientdb-gremlin

git checkout develop

mvn clean install
```

(I'm running MacOS 10.11.5, Oracle Java 1.8.0_92, Maven 3.3.9)

Comment: Hi Jim yes i did change that in develop since we are starting to make the integration for OrientDB 3.0

Comment: If you want to try it out you can use the latest release from maven central
that should work with OrientDB 2.2.x

http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.michaelpollmeier%7Corientdb-gremlin%7C3.2.3.0%7Cjar